# How to create choropleth world map with insets where necessary in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, r-sf

I wish to create choropleth world map with insets showing small regions hardly discernible in world map. Below is an example of the kind of world map I wish to plot:
[image]

The above figure is from an article in the Lance, ["Global, regional, and national age-sex-specific mortality for 282 causes of death in 195 countries and territories, 1980–2017: a systematic analysis for the Global Burden of Disease Study 2017".](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(18)32203-7/fulltext) In this figure, below the world map, many small regions are magnified in insets.

I am able to create a world map in R, but only the large map without insets. But I would like to ask if there is R code readily available to create insets for these small locations?

Comment: Hi! If you can use [`tmap`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tmap/index.html), I suggest you check the [inset map chapter](https://geocompr.robinlovelace.net/adv-map.html#inset-maps) of GecompR

Comment: See also an approach using `plot()`. You can combine that with the `cartography` package. https://dieghernan.github.io/201911_QuickR/

Comment: 1/16/2023 - When I run the code here, the inset maps are empty, and I cannot figure out why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best strategy will be to make the plots individually and then stitch them together. Here's a quick and dirty example.

```
library(ggplot2)   # use development version for coord limits in unprojected coordinates
library(sf)        # for manipulation of simple features objects
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.1, GDAL 3.1.1, PROJ 6.3.1
library(rnaturalearth) # for map data
library(dplyr)     # for mutate()
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(cowplot)   # for plot_grid()

world_sf <- ne_countries(returnclass = "sf") %>%
  mutate(log_pop = log(pop_est))

# Robinson projection
crs_robin <- "+proj=robin +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +x0=0 +y0=0"

# base plot
base <- ggplot() + 
  geom_sf(data = world_sf, aes(fill = log_pop), size = 0.2) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c()

# world
p1 <- base + theme_minimal() +
  coord_sf(crs = crs_robin)

# theme for inset plots
theme_inset <- theme_void() + 
  theme(
    panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", fill = NA),
    plot.margin = margin(2, 2, 2, 2)
  )

# North America
p2 <- base + theme_inset +
  coord_sf(crs = crs_robin, xlim = c(-150, -50), ylim = c(20, 70)) +
  guides(fill = "none")

# Australia
p3 <- base + theme_inset +
  coord_sf(crs = crs_robin, xlim = c(110, 155), ylim = c(-10, -45)) +
  guides(fill = "none")

# UK
p4 <- base + theme_inset +
  coord_sf(crs = crs_robin, xlim = c(-11, 2), ylim = c(49, 59)) +
  guides(fill = "none")

# Island
p5 <- base + theme_inset +
  coord_sf(crs = crs_robin, xlim = c(-25, -12), ylim = c(62, 68)) +
  guides(fill = "none")

# Svalbard
p6 <- base + theme_inset +
  coord_sf(crs = crs_robin, xlim = c(10.5, 26.5), ylim = c(75, 84)) +
  guides(fill = "none")

inset_row <- plot_grid(
  p2,
  plot_grid(NULL, p4, p5, p6, NULL, ncol = 1),
  p3,
  nrow = 1, rel_widths = c(1, .4, 1)
)

plot_grid(p1, inset_row, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-11-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

To get the plots to tile nicely, you'll have to make sure that all the inset plots have the correct aspect ratio. You can do that by setting the x and y limits of the insets accordingly. I set the limits in unprojected coordinates here, to get this together quickly, but you'll have more control over the exact aspect ratios by setting limits in projected coordinates (that's the only thing you can do in the currently released ggplot2 version anyways).